# Node.js and Express - How to get my actual location

Tags: node.js, api, geolocation

I am  fairly new to Node.js and Express. Is there a module or some code to help you get the actual location of the browser viewing the node.js app? I need the longitude and latitude or at least the zip code.

Thanks

Comment: Search the npm repo for `geolocation`: https://www.npmjs.com/browse/keyword/geolocation

Comment: I think GeoIP is outdated !

Comment: You cant do it reliable. You can guess the Location based on the ip, but this is just a rough assumption because ips are **not** bound to a location they only **might** be  mainly used in one location. For some ISP it might work for some ISP it might fail. If you want to use the IP for a rough guess use e.g. GeoIP2 or geoip-light.

Comment: @t.niese Thank you sir GeoIP2 will do the job !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found on other post this solution

[Best node.js module for finding location?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16664623/best-node-js-module-for-finding-location])

And recommends this module [GeoIP](https://github.com/kuno/GeoIP)

I hope it helps you

Roth.

Comment: I know that you cannot write comments. But you should not create an answer that only contains a link to another question/answer without providing any additional information that is not given in those answers.